# BASH Script that loops thru 4 different text files

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to create a BASH script that takes data from four different text files and assigns each line from each of the text files to a variable and then run a command using those variables. I already have a for loop constructed to do this task but the challenge I'm having is the for loop isn't doing one on one mapping.

I want this loop to iterate thru every line and run the command once per line and stop the loop when it reaches the EOF. When I run this script, I get the output as follows;

```
The username is jsmith The hostname is 0000-Ubuntu The description is P-Ubuntu The IP is 0.0.0.0/24

The username is jsmith The hostname is 0000-Ubuntu The description is P-Ubuntu The IP is 1.1.1.1/24

The username is jsmith The hostname is 0000-Ubuntu The description is P-Ubuntu The IP is 2.2.2.2/24
```

I need this to be one one one mapped; for example:

```
The username is jsmith The hostname is 0000-Ubuntu The description is P-Ubuntu The IP is 0.0.0.0/24

The username is pstone The hostname is 1111-Ubuntu The description is P-Ubuntu The IP is 1.1.1.1/24

The username is drogers The hostname is 3333-Ubuntu The description is P-Ubuntu The IP is 3.3.3.3/24
```

and so on....

As you can tell, I'm a newbie in bash scripting and I'd really appreciate any guidance/help.

Thanks!

```bash
#!/bin/bash
HOSTNAMES=$(cat /home/squadri/hostnames.txt)
DESCRIPTIONS=$(cat /home/squadri/descriptions.txt)
USERNAMES=$(cat /home/squadri/usernames.txt)
IPS=$(cat /home/squadri/ips.txt)

for i in $HOSTNAMES ; do
for j in $DESCRIPTIONS ; do
for k in $USERNAMES ; do
for l in $IPS ; do
        echo "The username is $k"
        echo "The hostname is $i"
        echo "The description is $j"
        echo "The IP is $l"
            done
       done
     done
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `paste` command for that:

```
paste /home/squadri/{hostnames,descriptions,usernames,ips}.txt |\
while read hostname description username ip; do
    echo "The username is $username"
    echo "The hostname is $hostname"
    echo "The description is $description"
    echo "The IP is $ip"
done
```

One potential pitfall with this approach is whitespace characters in your files but it should work fine if there are none in any of the lines in your files.

Comment: Awesome!! I found this method to be the simplest way to accomplish my specific task. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Read from 4 different file descriptors:

```
while IFS= read -r hostname;
      IFS= read -r description <&3;
      IFS= read -r username <&4;
      IFS= read -r ip <&5; do
  echo "The username is $username"
  echo "The hostname is $hostname"
  echo "The description is $description"
  echo "The IP is $ip"
done < hostnames.txt 3< descriptions.txt 4< usernames.txt 5< ips.txt
```

Technically, this reads until the end of `descriptions.txt`, regardless of the length of the other files. To stop when the shortest file ends, join the commands with `&&`:

```
while IFS= read -r hostname &&
      IFS= read -r description <&3 &&
      IFS= read -r username <&4 &&
      IFS= read -r ip <&5; do
  echo "The username is $username"
  echo "The hostname is $hostname"
  echo "The description is $description"
  echo "The IP is $ip"
done < hostnames.txt 3< descriptions.txt 4< usernames.txt 5< ips.txt
```

Iterating until you reach the end of the longest file is a little more complex (you can't simply join the commands with `||`), so I'll leave it as an exercise to the interested reader unless requested.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I'm sure this would work too. However, the answer above from another user is just simpler and serves my purpose. Thanks again.